# location.href in double quote : Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My code for select is below

```
<select id="ddlLanguages" class="form-control">
    @foreach($Languages as $Language) 
        <option onchange="location.href = {!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}" 
              value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This produces below html

```
<select id="ddlLanguages" class="form-control">
    <option onchange="location.href = http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/1" 
                    value="1">English</option>
    <option onchange="location.href = http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/2" 
                    value="2">French</option>
</select>
```

Problem is this part `"location.href = http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/1"` I am missing some formatting in the URL.

Can you guide me the correct path?

Comment: You want when an option is selected to redirect to a certain path?

Comment: Yes, Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Not exactly, do you use jQuery or I should provide vanilla js solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**JS Code**

```
$('#ddlLanguages').change(function(){
    location.href = $(this).find(":selected").attr('data-url');
});
```

**Server Side**

```
<select id="ddlLanguages" class="form-control">
    @foreach($Languages as $Language) 
        <option data-id="{!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}" 
              value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Your `<option>`s have `data-url` attribute, but your javascript is looking for `data-id` attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my mistake. Corrected now. :)

Comment: `data-url` was more relevant than `data-id` in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<option onchange="location.href = {!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}" 
              value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
```

to this:

```
<option onchange="location.href = '{!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}'" 
              value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
```

The url you pass to location.href must be a string, that is why you need to surround the entire url with single quotes.

Comment: Now it is like this `onchange="location.href = 'http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/1'"` and still not redirecting to Url on change

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="ddlLanguages" class="form-control">
    @foreach($Languages as $Language) 
        <option data-url="{!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}" 
              value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>


<script>
$('#ddlLanguages').on('change', function () {
  var url = $(this).attr('data-url'); // get selected value
  if (url) { // require a URL
    window.location = url; // redirect
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` shouldn't be put on the `<option>`s, but on the `<select>`, because the `<option>` hasn't changed. By selecting an option, you're changing the `<select>`. If you want to redirect based on `<option>` selection. Do the following:

```
var select = document.getElementById('ddlLanguages');
select.onchange = function() {
  location.href = select[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-location');
}
```

*See below for jQuery version of this javascript snippet.*

Put this javascript somewhere in your page. And your `<options>` should have `data-location`.

```
<option data-location="{!! URL('Tr/' . '/' . $Language->LID) !!}" value="{!! $Language->LanguageID !!}">{!! $Language->Language !!}</option>
```

Or you can change your options to "redirect" on `click`:

```
<select id="ddlLanguages" class="form-control">
  <option onclick="location.href = http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/1" value="1">English</option>
  <option onclick="location.href = http://localhost/Learning/public/Translation/2" value="2">French</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ddlLanguages').change(function(){
         location.href = $(this).data('location');
    });
});
```